# Silverlight how to bind properties to List item values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I am new to XAML and playing around with the features. At this stage I am creating a datagrid populated with static data.

I want to know how to disable certain rows, I tried binding the IsEnabled Property to the model and then giving it boolean values like so:

**EDIT:**
**XAML**

```
 <UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="#AAEAEFF4"/>
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="#00FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="Column"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="DragIndicatorStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7FFFFFFF"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Grid>
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unsorted"/>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SortAscending">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="SortDescending">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-.9" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="SortIcon"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#66808080" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill">
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.015"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="SortIcon" Grid.Column="1" Data="F1 M -5.215,6.099L 5.215,6.099L 0,0L -5.215,6.099 Z " Fill="#7FFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="8">
                                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY=".9" ScaleX=".9"/>
                                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="DropLocationIndicatorStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3F4346"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Vertical"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#FFC9CACA"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding enabled}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopLeftHeaderTemplate" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                                <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                            </Border>
                                            <Rectangle Fill="#FFDBDCDC" Height="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TopRightHeaderTemplate" TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Background="#FF1F3B53" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                                <Rectangle Stretch="Fill">
                                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#FCFFFFFF" Offset="0.015"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#F7FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.6"/>
                                                            <GradientStop Color="#D1FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                </Rectangle>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <sdk:DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="TopLeftCornerHeader" Template="{StaticResource TopLeftHeaderTemplate}" Width="22"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="TopRightCornerHeader" Grid.Column="2" Template="{StaticResource TopRightHeaderTemplate}"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="ColumnHeadersAndRowsSeparator" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="#FFC9CACA" Height="1" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
                                <sdk:DataGridRowsPresenter x:Name="RowsPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BottomRightCorner" Grid.Column="2" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BottomLeftCorner" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollbar" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,-1,-1,-1" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Width="18"/>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FrozenColumnScrollBarSpacer"/>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollbar" Grid.Column="1" Height="18" Margin="-1,0,-1,-1" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <sdk:ValidationSummary x:Name="ValidationSummary" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MaxHeight="90" Grid.Row="3"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Background="#8CFFFFFF" CornerRadius="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="McDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}"/>

</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Data();
        McDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;

    }

    public List<Model> list = new List<Model>();
    private List<Model> Data()
    {
        list.Add(new Model(1, "Test", "1", true));
        list.Add(new Model(2, "Ger", "2", true));
        list.Add(new Model(3, "dsg", "3", true));
        list.Add(new Model(4, "Hd", "4", false));
        list.Add(new Model(5, "TeHRFdgst", "5", false));
        return list;
    }

    public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Prop { get; set; }
        public bool enabled { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Model(int id, string name, string prop, bool isenabled)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Prop = prop;
            enabled = isenabled;

        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

But this far it only adds a column for IsEnabled as expected, but I thought it would also set the property value as well.

Could someone maybe explain how the binding between the XAML and C# works if it is even possible this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable DataGridRows depending on a bool flag in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997882/disable-datagridrows-depending-on-a-bool-flag-in-wpf)

Comment: Could you please post your full XAML markup? Where is the setter defined and what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I added the full XAML @mm8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `RowStyle` to disable a row:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding enabled}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
...
    </Setter>
```

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly, I see what you did there thanks!